# Javascript / Blockchain.info Websocket API Address Subscription

Tags: javascript, websocket, bitcoin, blockchain.info-api

I am new to bitcoin, Blockchain.info API and javascript, however, i am trying to implement a code that tracks Live Payments notification on a particular bitcoin address. The idea here is... after the user scans the QR image `<img src="http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chl=12fMma2J15qre9bZPsX3AerdgWd9Poe9ee">`, and makes payment to the BTC address, `12fMma2J15qre9bZPsX3AerdgWd9Poe9ee`, the Div with ID `#websocket` will instantly display Live (without refreshing the webpage), the amount of Bitcoins Transaferred to the address, thus switching the initial content of the div from `monitoring...` to the amount transferred `Recieved: 0.003 BTC`.

I have written a piece of code ... but i'm not sure what i'm missing. Please Help. Thank you.

The code:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 "> 
                <img src="http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chl=12fMma2J15qre9bZPsX3AerdgWd9Poe9ee"> 
                <div id="websocket">
                    Monitoring Transactions ...
                </div>

                <script>
                var btcs = new WebSocket("12fMma2J15qre9bZPsX3AerdgWd9Poe9ee");
                btcs.onopen = function() {
                    btcs.send(JSON.stringify({"op":"addr_sub", "addr":"12fMma2J15qre9bZPsX3AerdgWd9Poe9ee"}));
                };

                btcs.onmessage = function (onmsg) {
                    var response = JSON.parse(onmsg.data);
                    var getOutputs = response.x.out;
                    var countOuts = getOutputs.length;

                    for (i=0; i < countOuts; i++){
                        var outAdd = response.x.out[i].addr;
                        var address = "12fMma2J15qre9bZPsX3AerdgWd9Poe9ee";
                        if (outAdd == address){
                            var amount =response.x.out[i].value;
                            var calAmount = Amount / 100000000;
                            document.getElementById("websocket").innerHTML = "Recieved" + calAmount + "BTC";
                        }
                    }
                };
                </script>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <!-- more html stuff goes here -->
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anywhere in the code a connection being made to blockchain's api, so I'm guessing this

```
var btcs = new WebSocket("12fMma2J15qre9bZPsX3AerdgWd9Poe9ee");
```

should use the api's address instead of the target bitcoin wallet address.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to put `wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv` while starting a new socket at the place of address.

Comment: above WebSocket api will not work for TestNet address??

Answer (score 1):

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 "> 
            <img src="http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chl=12fMma2J15qre9bZPsX3AerdgWd9Poe9ee"> 
            <div id="websocket">
                Monitoring Transactions ...
            </div>

            <script>
            var btcs = new WebSocket("wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv");
            btcs.onopen = function() {
                btcs.send(JSON.stringify({"op":"addr_sub", "addr":"12fMma2J15qre9bZPsX3AerdgWd9Poe9ee"}));
            };

            btcs.onmessage = function (onmsg) {
                var response = JSON.parse(onmsg.data);
                var getOutputs = response.x.out;
                var countOuts = getOutputs.length;

                for (i=0; i < countOuts; i++){
                    var outAdd = response.x.out[i].addr;
                    var address = "12fMma2J15qre9bZPsX3AerdgWd9Poe9ee";
                    if (outAdd == address){
                        var amount =response.x.out[i].value;
                        var calAmount = Amount / 100000000;
                        document.getElementById("websocket").innerHTML = "Recieved" + calAmount + "BTC";
                    }
                }
            };
            </script>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <!-- more html stuff goes here -->
        </div>
    </div>
```